# How to get screenshot of the complete cookie banner of webpage in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, banner

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCwks.png)

I am able to get the full screenshot of the webpage but not the cookie banner.Can i do it in selenium or i should use any other tool

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You can take a screenshot of a specific WebElement by using `element.screenshot(path)`

Comment: @soundwave is there any way I can get the full screenshot of the cookie banner with scrollable content

Comment: I know a way but using the headless mode, i will write an answer on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a screenshot of the complete banner, you have to enlarge the banner so that all the scrollable content is visible. However, if your computer screen resolution is 1920x1080 or lower, the complete banner will not fit your screen, so in this case you have to use the browser in headless mode. In this mode you can resize the browser to whatever desired size. This is the working code

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")

chromedriver_path = '...'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=Service(chromedriver_path))

driver.get('https://www.pcgamer.com/uk/')
time.sleep(2)
# click the button "MORE OPTIONS"
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(.,'MORE OPTIONS')]").click()
time.sleep(2)
# resize the browser window
driver.set_window_size(1300, 1400)
banner = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[role=dialog]')
# resize the banner
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'max-height: 1100px;')", banner)
time.sleep(1)
banner.screenshot('banner_screenshot.png')
```

and this is the image you will obtain

[image]